# Problems squaring # in C

Tags: rounding-error

I'm trying to compile a program in C to return the square of a number, for instance 1^2=1, but the program compiles without issues and always returns a value of 0.

What did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
/* Define temporary variables */
double value1, value2;
double result;

/* Assign the values we will use for the pow calculation */
value1 = 0;
value2 = 0;

/* Calculate the result of value1 raised to the power of value2 */
result = pow(value1, value2);

/* Display the result of the calculation */
printf("%f raised to the power of %f is %f\n", value1, value2, result);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The description at the top indicates its just for squares.  You could easily accomplish that just by multiplying it by its self without pow() function.  Also, if its 0, then you're having an issue setting the variables.... apparently the description is no longer there... BUT IT WAS.

Comment: @M.Jameson pls check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can compute exponent or power with pow function:

```
#include <math.h>
double pow(double x, double y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple error.  You forgot to call the `[mySquare setPowering];` function.  Also you were passing some weird unused into to that function so i clipped it out.

Here's your fixed code.  Though next time you should fine tooth comb your code before asking us.  Otherwise, you won't learn important debugging skills.  The best method for that is to just literally walk line by line and make sure everything is being used correctly... thats how i found the error :)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <math.h>

@interface Square: NSObject
{
    int Constant;
    int Power;
    int Powering;
}
-(void) print;
-(void) setConstant: (int) c;
-(void) setPower: (int) p;
-(void) setPowering;   // <-- HERE
@end
@implementation Square
-(void) print
{
    NSLog (@"%i", Powering);
}
-(void) setConstant: (int) c
{
    Constant = c;
}
-(void) setPower: (int) p
{
    Power = p;
}
-(void) setPowering   // <-- HERE
{
    NSLog (@"%i^%i", Constant, Power); // This is optional

    Powering = pow(Constant,Power);
}
@end
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Square *mySquare;
    mySquare = [Square alloc];
    mySquare = [mySquare init];
    [mySquare setConstant: 2];
    [mySquare setPower: 3];
    [mySquare setPowering]; // <-- HERE
    NSLog (@"The value of myPower is:");
    [mySquare print];

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code:

```
[mySquare setConstant: 2];
[mySquare setPower: 3];
NSLog (@"The value of myPower is:");
[mySquare print];
```

1. I think you need to call `[mySquare setPowering]` for Powering be calculated.
2. `[mySquare print]` is new to me. This is trying to print the class? I think that's weird. I think you should print the `mySquare.Powering` to check the value. Try something like

   ```
   NSLog("Powering: %d",mySquare.Powering);
   ```
3. Not sure why you are using INT for floating point calculations. That could affect your results too I think. best to use float for all variables.

That's all my comment.